# How to map/join two tables and filter by parameters using dapper

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, asp.net-core, dapper

I want to join two tables that have a relationship with each other,
In the **Customer table**, there are **two columns for deleted and approved**. Get the Customer that are approved and not deleted then match the Customer with the Loan table Using CustId **(Both Tables has CustId)** and Filter by supplied parameters

- Deleted=0
- Approved=1

Passed Parameters are(And they can be optional) User can pass only one or two or more than 2
InterestRate
LoanTrfDate
LastPaymentDate

```
        public async Task<IEnumerable<Loan>> ManageGettingAll(string InterestRate, string LoanTrfDate, string LastPaymentDate)
        {
            IEnumerable<Loan> loans = null;

            //var sql = "Select * from MonthlyInterest where LoanAccountNo=@Id AND Deleted=@Deleted AND CAST(TranDate AS DATE) BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate";
            try{

                using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connectionstring))
                {
                    await conn.OpenAsync();

                    var parameters = new 
                    { 
                        InterestRate = InterestRate, 
                        LoanTrfDate = LoanTrfDate, 
                        LastPaymentDate = LastPaymentDate
                    };
                   
                string sql = "Select l.*, c.FirstName_CompanyName from dbo.Loan l left join Customer where and l.Deleted = 0 and and l.Approved = 1 c on  l.CustId=c.CustId Where InterestRate=@InterestRate AND CAST(LoanTrfDate AS DATE)=@LoanTrfDate AND CAST(LastPaymentDate AS DATE)=@LastPaymentDate";
                 
                    loans = await conn.QueryAsync<Loan>(sql, parameters);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                throw;
            }


            return loans;
        }
```

Comment: To be clear, your question is how to filter by parameters only if a value was specified? And ignore the parameters of they are null?

Comment: At least one parameter must be passed

Comment: You can use DynamicParameters object. you can check if the passed string is not null then only add those to DynamicParameters  object. And in SQL side you can use ISNULL(@InterestRate ,InterestRate) or Coalease function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to filter by a parameter only if it's not null, you can use the SQL below.

```
Select l.*, c.FirstName_CompanyName 
from dbo.Loan l 
left join Customer c on l.CustId=c.CustId 
where l.Deleted = 0 and l.Approved = 1
and (@InterestRate is null or InterestRate=@InterestRate) 
AND (@LastPaymentDate is null or (CAST(LoanTrfDate AS DATE)=@LoanTrfDate AND CAST(LastPaymentDate AS DATE)=@LastPaymentDate))
```

to check that at least one parameter was set, you can add this if statement.

```
if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(LoanTrfDate) && string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(LastPaymentDate))
{
    throw new Exception("Some clear message here.");
}
```